# Why do mobile HTML geolocation apps get fewer location updates than native apps?

Tags: iphone, html, geolocation, gps, mobile-safari

I noticed that HTML5 geolocation position updates do not arrive as often as native Apps position updates.

While the location in iphone's native maps App moves smoothly, the position on google's mobile maps page jumps from point to point when driving a car.

I assumed that mobile safari gets its position from the OS, so shouldn't the both be synchronous?

Comment: My guess is that the iOS Maps app interpolates between location updates using speed and heading info, or perhaps by estimating those things using previous fixes.

Comment: Geolocation is not part of HTML5.

Comment: I can't imagine that the Javascript API for gelocation is directly linked to the core GPS / IP address / cell mapping that goes on in the device. My guess is that there is some sort of cacheing in the Javascript layer, if only to stop a Mobile Safari page draining the battery in double-quick time.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are getting the location in Safari it only gets the Geo Location as Fast as it is specified in the Javascript Function, Basically if the webpage asks for the link and the location is under the specified Time Frame then it will leave the Location where it is at. If the Location is Too old then the webpage gets a new location and that process starts over.

Thats the way it used to work, and i am still looking into how the details work but thats what i have come across so far. - and is probably outdated now But Hey its still cool!